# tan inverse in matlab not giving correct values

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, inverse, atan2

As a part of a longer code, I get a quantity phi1 and phi2 (matrices of size 128x128) which are the arguments of a complex quantity. Now I define the following quantities in MATLAB:

```
alpha=phi1-phi2;
S1=cos(alpha);
S2=sin(alpha);
K=atan2(S2,S1);
```

Now, K should be equal to alpha. Therefore, the matrix B defined as:

```
B=K-alpha;
```

should be zero.But the result is coming out to be different. Though several elements of B are zero, a lot of them have the value 6.2832 (i.e 2pi).
Why this could be happening?

Comment: Actually, phi1 and phi2 are angles evaluated in MATLAB. Hence their ranges lie between -pi and pi. when I evaluate alpha the range of the values lie no more between -pi and pi. Hence, atan2 is not giving the exact alpha value. But the thing is that I want exact alpha value, because there is another equation giving beta=phi1+phi2. And my main aim is to evaluate phi1 by deriving alpha from S1 and S2 and the beta equation. For that I want exact alpha value, as it is. But no matter what I try I am not able to retrieve alpha exactly. Can anyone please suggest something?

Answer (score 2):

The [`atan2`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html) function always [returns values between `-pi` and `pi`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html#buct8h0-4). So, for example, for `alpha = 4` your code

```
S1=cos(alpha);
S2=sin(alpha);
K=atan2(S2,S1)
```

gives

```
K =
  -2.2832
```

which is `alpha` but moved (modulo `2*pi`) to the interval between `-pi` and `pi`.

This shouldn't be a problem, because two angles that differ by `2*pi` are actually the same. So a possible solution is to compare the angles by doing the subtraction modulo `2*pi`:

```
>> mod(alpha-K, 2*pi)
ans =
     0
```

Note also that, due to [numerical rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/2586922), you should not rely on the difference modulo `2*pi` being exactly `0`. Instead, compare its absolute value to a given tolerance.